# SQL query: how to display the name of a person having the minimum/maximum account balance

Tags: mysql

I have this table and values below and i need to

> DISPLAY THE NAME OF THE ACCOUNT HAVING MINIMUM BALANCE ALSO THE NAME HAVING THE MAX BALANCE IN PUNE BRANCH.

Any help would be wonderful. Thank you.

```
CREATE TABLE account
(
   cust_name   CHAR (15),
   acc_no      CHAR (5),
   branch      CHAR (15),
   balance     INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO account
     VALUES ("aman",
             "100",
             "nagpur",
             50000)
, ("bhushan","101","jaipur",2500),("cindy","102","mumbai",0);

INSERT INTO account
     VALUES ("dinesh",
             "103",
             "pune",
             23000)
, ("ellie","104","jaipur",12000),("frank","105","pune",350);

INSERT INTO account
     VALUES ("himesh",
             "106",
             "bhopal",
             5000)
, ("ishan","107","mumbai",100000),("jatin","108","nagpur",1000);

INSERT INTO account
     VALUES ("kumar",
             "109",
             "jaipur",
             8000);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work on all databases

```
Select cust_name from account where balance = (select max(balance) from account)   and branch = "Pune"
Union all 
Select cust_name from account where balance = (select min(balance) from account) and branch = "Pune"
```

Comment: It's not giving an output

Comment: @NishidWalde Is it giving an error or blank result set